# Retrieve quality profiles for a given project in SonarQube

Tags: api, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

How to get the project's applied profiles (quality profiles) using the web service api (which URL and parameters ?)

I use SonarQube 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use the `/api/qualityprofiles/search` WS:

- See [documentation on Nemo](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/qualityprofiles/search)
- See [live example on Nemo](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/qualityprofiles/search?projectKey=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube&format=json)